# Concatenation of the values of 3 columns row by row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to concatenate the values of columns (1, 2, 3). The result should be in column (4). There are n-rows for which the concatenation should be made. With the code I made, each row is worked on but the result in each result cell is added and added. What did I do wrong?

```
Sub insertStatement()
Dim row As Integer
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim x As String
Dim cel As Range
Dim rng As Range

Sheets("INSERT").Select
row = 1
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

Do While Cells(row, "A").Value <> ""
    With Worksheets("INSERT")
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lrow, 3))
    End With

    x = ""

    For Each cel In rng

        x = x & cel.Value

    Next

    Sheets("Insert").Cells(row, 4).Value = x

row = row + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: If you put a `Debug.Print rng.Address` before the `x = ""`, you will know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below for this simple goal.

```
Sub insertStatement()
    Const sFormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-3],RC[-2],RC[-1])"
    Dim lLastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INSERT")
        lLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        .Range("D1:D" & lLastRow).FormulaR1C1 = sFormulaR1C1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I never thought about that way of solving my problem. I have to study what you proposed but most important, it works!

Comment: Great to hear you will study it, this combines Excel built-in function **=concatenate(text1,text2,etc.)** and use VBA to fill in the formulas in one go (with Relative Formula).

Answer (score 0):

At the line where you are setting your range...

```
Set rng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lrow, 3))
```

...you are using row 1, column 1 as your start point every time.  Would suggest the following...

```
Set rng = Range(.Cells(row, 1), .Cells(lrow, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tested the code and now it concatenates the last row and uses that value for each row?

Comment: When I use row instead of lrow in the first cell range then it works. Thanks!

Comment: I see - that makes sense - thanks for the adjustment - editing answer.